# Can these exterior wall layers be used in this configuration?

Tags: walls, insulation

Can I use these materials in a wall, from exterior?

- house wrap
- OSB
- 1-1/2" foam (Thermal Star x grade or Foamular 150)
- R-19 unfaced insulation
- poly vapor barrier

Comment: Please revise to add information about your regional climate.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the climate in your region.

Your proposed foam is closed-cell, so in milder moist climates (such as the Pacific West Coast) there should be no further vapor barrier on the inside. Otherwise you'll risk trapping moisture. This is also a concern with air conditioned homes in hot and humid climates.

With thick enough rigid closed-cell insulation against the outside wall, the dew point on a mildly cold day, will be somewhere within the rigid foam. Based on moisture and the temperature gradient along the cross section of the wall, there will be no condensation against the foam surface at the fibre glass insulation.

In other regions with very dry and very cold winters different considerations apply.

As for Total R calculation, you have to sum up all the components based on R/inch and the thickness (incl. sheathing & drywall), and compare it to the number required in your jurisdiction per building code. Sometimes there is NO insulation requirement for below grade installation, so anything goes. Just keep the foam against the outside face of the wall cavity, and fill the rest of the cavity with fiberglass, to the drywall. (And not the other way around)

Comment: It's a barmaminum  he was thinking from outside in tyvek osb then 1 1/2 foam then r19 faced insulation on inside before drywall

Comment: Yes agree, that's how I see the sandwich too, except I don't know what you mean with "barmaminum"? Bare minimum?

Comment: no a pole barn home

Comment: ah, a "barndominium"... ok. so you are asking about above grade, so same answer.

Comment: As far as the order of the materials go - when I had my house renovated 6 years ago & they redid some of the outer wall, from outside to in it was Hardi Plank, Tyvek, 1" insul panel, OSB, studs & 3-1/2" Rockwool, 1/2" sheet rock.

Comment: sounds like continuous insulation outside the studs, very good. Depends on local building code whether that's required. In any case OP needs to avoid the VB, like yours.

Comment: @isherwood double vapour retarding is disallowed in my area (Pacific West Coast). The rigid foam must be thick enough so that the dew point is within it. FG insulation must breath to the inside. Perhaps not possible at Minnesota temperatures, and you don't have our moisture problems.

Comment: @isherwood good point. edited.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unless you're in a very hot, moist region. Well, *almost*.

My father just retired as the local Habitat for Humanity construction manager. In an effort to achieve better-than-standard energy efficiency in his homes he's been using exactly what you describe here for exterior walls, with two exceptions:

- The OSB is *inside* the foam (walls should be built with the framing in direct contact with the sheathing for proper strength)
- The foam is 1"

This strategy has the blessing of the local building inspection office.

In a cold climate it's critical that you have a vapor barrier to the interior to prevent the moisture of habitation from migrating out to the frost zone in the insulation. What happens on the outside of the insulation layer is less of a concern. Moisture doesn't tend to accumulate during the cooling season, at least here in Minnesota.